# Set 100% in width for Google Maps image API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, width

I'm using [Google Maps image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/) and I want to use 100% width on the image but I can only set a fixed width to it. If it possible, how can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this page of Mike Williams' Google Maps Javascript API v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm)

You need to add width:100% to *all* the elements that contain the map.

[example from the documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/map-simple)

Comment: I noticed now that this didn't worked at all :( You can see it in action here: http://vadret-just.nu/ and then click on the "Geografisk position" link over the temperature. The container is 100% but not the map

Comment: I know. If you don't want to share your position, here's the same code on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/h5cru/. But the map is being 100% in width on jsFiddle but the map is quite bigger. How can I keep the original size for the map?

Comment: That sounds like a clue to the issue.  I don't understand what you mean by "How can I keep the original size for the map?", if you are using percentage sizing, the browser will dynamically size it to be 100% of its parent element.  Is it not doing that?

Comment: Please see my updated code on jsFiddle. The quality on the second map is not as blurry as the first map. Is it possible to get the rid of the blurry effect on the first map with 100% in width?